# What's the difference between @input and @change in Vue <input type="file">?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

Please see these two code snippets, they all output the same results:

```
<template>
  <input type="file" @input="input" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    input(event) {
      console.log(event.target.files);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <input type="file" @change="change" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    change(event) {
      console.log(event.target.files);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Is there any difference between `@input` and `@change` event in `<input type="file" />` element?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These events are inherited from the javascript events `oninput` and `onchange` and according to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20is%20that%20the,works%20on%20elements.) you could see the difference :

> The oninput event occurs when an element gets user input.
> This event occurs when the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` element is changed.
> Tip: This event is similar to the [`onchange`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event. The difference is that the `oninput` event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while `onchange` occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed. The other difference is that the `onchange` event also works on `<select>` elements.

Example with simple input text :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    input() {
      console.log("input")
    },
    change() {
      console.log("change")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input @change="change" @input="input" />
</div>
```

Comment: pressing **'enter'** will trigger `onchange` as well when some changes already made.

Comment: Yes and it could submit the form if that input is wrapped by a form element